# Uncaught exception onReject callback Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, babeljs

Since yesterday , I try to understand a behavior that I did not know about *onReject* Promise callback. In fact, I work with an API (return json data) and Superagent for make request. I have this class:

```
class Api
{
    constructor(uri) {
        ...
    }

    // Simple GET HTTP Request
    get(...) {
        var url = this.buildUrl(...);
        this.requestPending = request.get(url);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.requestPending.end((err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(res.body.error);
                } else {
                    resolve(res.body);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

What I do not understand is that:

```
reject(res.body.error);
```

throw an exception (res.body.error contains a simple string). Indeed, firebug display this error:

```
uncaught exception: ...
```

Could you explain this behavior ?

PS: I work with **babel** for transpile js.

**Edit**

I tested with *when* librairie but I have the same result. However, when I write:

```
reject(new Error("foo"));
```

The *onReject* callback is never call:

```
when.all([
   api.get(...),
   api.get(...)
]).then(data => {
   console.log(data)
}, err => {
   console.log(err);
})
```

and in the browser:

[image: Promise reject error]

I continue my research.

**Edit 2**

Really sorry , I deserve to be whipped on the public square !!!. In fact, I had to change one file instead of two. Really, really sorry !!

Comment: Well for whatever reason accessing `res.body.error` is throwing an error, try and find out why that is the case (e.g. it doesn't exist).

Comment: In fact, it's not `res.body.error` is throwing an error because when i write `reject("foo")` it's the same result.

Comment: Or the actual `this.requestPending.end` function is throwing an error. Did you read what the exception said?

Comment: Put the content of the function inside a try/catch

Comment: No, the exception isn't catch. In fact, I use `Promise.all` (which send several request). I just tested  with one promise. This time the _onReject_ callback on **.then** method have run. However, `Promise.all` should have the same behavoir that one promise ?!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether it is silly or not,may be the scope for requestPending might be the problem.sorry if it sounds silly,

```
 var url = this.buildUrl(...),self = this;
        this.requestPending = request.get(url);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            self.requestPending.end((err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(res.body.error);
                } else {
                     resolve(res.body);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No it's not. Arrow functions do preserve the `this` *context*  (not "scope", btw)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, there is a mistake in my code. In fact, I `bind(this)` the function

Comment: @Jean: It makes no sense to `.bind()` an arrow function that has lexical `this`?

Comment: Yes, excuse me, I keep the old syntax, in my code, with `function`. I update the code. Thanks.